# Syntax differences between Windows and Linux

Tags: r, linux, windows, syntax

I am a user of R on windows, and I notice that there are simple differences when I use R on Linux, considering this example:

```
a
10.3
14.7
11.4
10.6
```

On Linux when I use this command:

```
mean (df [,1])
```

I get the mean normally, but when I do it on Windows, I get this error:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default (df[,1]): argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Does anyone know if I can fix this on Windows and use this `mean(df [,1])`, like Linux, because I need to use for looping.

NOTE: I know, if on Windows I use `mean(df$a)` I will be able to make the mean, but due to looping I need to work with previous way

My R version on Windows is:

```
"R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)"
```

Comment: this also works on Windows, are you sure you loaded df?

Comment: @Waldi, yes I´m. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a **very** strong suspicion that you are ending up with a `data.frame` on Linux and a `tibble` (the tidyverse extension of data frames) on Windows.  You can check by using `class(df)`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
mean(df[,1])
## [1] 2
df <- tibble(df)
mean(df[,1])
## [1] NA
## Warning message:
## In mean.default(df[, 1]) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The reason for this difference is that a one-column subset of a `data.frame` is a vector (unless you specify `drop=FALSE`), of class `numeric` if that was the class of the column you chose; a one-column subset of a `tibble` is a one-column tibble.

You can use `df[[1]]` (which works fine with loops/indirect indexing) to do what you want, or `as.data.frame(df)[,1]`; the first is probably better.